# Can I use multiple vpn connections to increase bandwidth

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, vpn, bandwidth

There is wifi network in our college and it only connected to local server so if we want to use internet we have to connect to a vpn server using our specific user/pass the problem is bandwidth is limited. Is there any way so I can use 3-4 connections work together to increase bandwidth?

Comment: Connecting to multiple VPN connections wouldn't increase your bandwidth.  Because you already need an internet connection to connect to the VPN in the first place, so your limits are the original, internet connection that allows you to connect to the VPN.

Comment: @Ramhound Vpn server is local , I can connect without internet connection at firs place

Comment: My argument still stands.  You can only get so many bits per second with your hardware.  Being connected multiple times will result in multiple connections and the same bits per second capacity will still exist.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to Ramhound, if I'm understanding you correctly, there is more bandwidth available, but the VPN caps you to a certain amount, correct?

If so, you might be able to use NIC bonding to do it, or possibly some sort of virtualized guests, each one running a VPN, then bond all of the virtualized adapters on the host.  It would be fairly difficult to do.  Is there any non-wifi access?  Many routers have ways to add more than one WAN interface.

Comment: yes there is way more bandwidth available but connections are limited . unfortunately the only way to connect to network is wifi

Comment: [Here](http://simonmott.co.uk/vpn-bonding) is a link to basically what I was saying.  They do it in Linux, I'm not sure that you can do the same thing on Windows, iirc bonding is only in the Server editions of Windows, but I may be wrong.  The basic premise here is that OpenVPN creates TUN or TAP adapters that work just like physical adapters.  You take those two TUN / TAP devices, and tell applications to treat them as one uber device, and you tell the kernel to load balance over them. Beware though, if your school has a decent IT department, you'll only get one connection per credential set.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, creative thinking, but sadly there is not any way to merge connections like that. Your best option is to consider getting a LTE / 4G MiFi or something similar, or using your LTE / 4G  cell phone as a hotspot.

Ideally, you should talk to the college's IT department to get the speed issue resolved, or provide some kind of workaround.

Comment: Speed limitations are by purpose there is no issue to be resolved , and what should I exactly do with mifi?

Comment: MiFi is essentially a hotspot by itself. Obviously I would be talking about an LTE / 4G version.

Comment: Whether it is intentionally capped or just an issue with network hardware, this is something only the IT department can resolve. You need to work with them on describing the problem you are having, and get them to resolve it.